# output consulta php CSV en una columna

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
$Name = 'NOMINA-'.$mes.'-'.$dia.'-'.$ano.'.csv';


$rpedidos = "SELECT total,
         cuenta FROM nomina";
          $reg = $conexion->query($rpedidos);
          while( $reg_File = $reg->fetch_array() )
          {
               $ceros="000";
     $ttpago=number_format($reg_File["total"],2);
    $ctaBco=$reg_File["cuenta"];
     $tt="".$ctaBco."".$ceros."".$ttpago."";
    $shtml = $tt."\n";

          }

//$shtml=$excel;  
//$shtml=$shtml."</table>";  
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");  
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");  
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$Name.''); 
echo $shtml;
```

El mismo me genera Perfectamente , CSV pero me divide los totales en dos columnas y solo lo necesito en una , alguna guía.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que los [`CSV`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valores_separados_por_comas) son archivos donde los valores son separados por:

- Coma (`,`)
- O! punto y coma (`;`) donde la configuración regional usa como separador decimal la coma, ejemplo: Argentina, Brasil, España, etc.

Para cualquiera de estos casos, la forma de *escapar* el separador es imprimir el valor entre comillas dobles (`"`).

Solución:

```
$tt = '"'.$ctaBco.$ceros.$ttpago.'"';
```

PD: Las comillas dobles se escapan con comillas doble, por ejemplo:

```
$valor = 'valor "con comillas"';
// En el CSV
"valor ""con comillas"""
```

Comment: Marcos muchísimas gracias una preguntita me imprime el valor todo junto pero separados entre comas cada dos números, entonces como quitarles entre estos estas comas , me imprime en excel 12,345,600,023,522.5  y quisiera que fueses completo de esta manera 12345600023522.5

Comment: @AlexanderQuiroz, no lo tomes a mal, pero esta es otra pregunta que nada tiene que ver con la anterior. Si mi respuesta te ha sido de ayuda considera votarla o es acertada marcarla como tal. Aún así, para conseguir tal resultado podrías ser hacer uso de [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php) para buscar las comas (`,`) y reemplazarlas por nada ('').